# What can be a dependency for React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Looking at the docs, there is a note at the bottom of [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) [edited link] that makes it seem like only props or state should be used in a hook dependency list. However, when a "complex expression" on props or state is used in the list, the eslint plugin gives the following:

> React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked. eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

This has me thinking about what is allowed to be used as a dependency. Can we use a local variable that is calculated from props? Do we need to create some sort of new state variable or ref in this case? I'm not certain if hooks are executed in place within the component (so local variables are available) or are hoisted out of the context of the render (so we have to use only state, props, or other hook values like refs/memos).

#### Examples

A component has a prop, data, that is an object.

```
data: {
  name: 'name',
  id: 2
}
```

1) It looks like `data.name` can be used in the dependencies. But can we use a local variable that is set to the property?

```js
const { name } = data;

useEffect(fn, [name]);
```

2) Would we be able to use a variable that is calculated by a prop in a dependency array?

```js
const isOdd = Boolean(data.id % 2);

useEffect(fn, [isOdd]);
```

---

Both cases seem to work with small tests. I'm not knowledgable enough with Hooks to know if it's breaking some rules that would leave the results as indeterminate.

Comment: "...makes it seem like only props or state should be used in a hook dependency list" How did you come to this conclusion? There's really no mention of state or props other than `useState` can access its own local state.

Comment: I had too many tabs open and copied the wrong link. Updated with correct link. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) may help understanding hook dependencies.

> **Note**
>
> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes **all values
>   from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over
>   time and that are used by the effect.** Otherwise, your code will
>   reference stale values from previous renders. Learn more about how to
>   deal with functions and what to do when the array changes too often.

The important bit, *"...all values from the component scope..."*, meaning any value within the component scope used within the hook.

**Q:** Can we use a local variable that is calculated from props?

- Yes

**Q:** Do we need to create some sort of new state variable or ref in this case?

- No

**Q:** I'm not certain if hooks are executed in place within the component (so local variables are available) or are hoisted out of the context of the render (so we have to use only state, props, or other hook values like refs/memos)

- AFAIK, they are just functions with special rules within react. They are invoked within the scope of the functional component.

Comment: The part I got confused on was later on that note. 

"If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run."

The second sentence here says that an empty array means it doesn't depend on states or props. But really, it mean that it doesn't depend on any values within the component scope. Is that right?

Comment: The bulk of the rest of that note discusses using a hook to simulate behavior you get from `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` class-based lifecycle functions and using the hook lint rules to help not make logical errors in hooks. Was there a specific part that is confusing for you?

Comment: You can think of hooks as being executed EXACTLY in place within the component - which is why hooks must be run in the same order and CANNOT be called conditionally. It's 100% necessary to include any variable that you use in the hook function that may change between renders. If you don't stuff will eventually break in a very confusing way. Hooks are memoized, so if the values in the dependency array haven't changed since the last time the hook was called, then the hook won't be called again.

Comment: Keeping the _"all values from the component scope"_ part in mind, the rest seems to make sense. Thank you for the help.